# how to display the latest updated records in table -Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having a table in the template file and I'm updating the data by using the .xls file.

Can anyone please help me with how to display the latest added records with some hint(or by adding another column) ***OR*** how to differentiate which are updated records and which are newly added records?

below is my logic code to upload data.

```
import time
import simplejson as json
count = [ ]  ##Global variable
lap =[]
from datetime import datetime
def CTA_upload(request):
    lap.clear()
    i = 1
    print('Counter value at starting::::::::: :', len(count))
    allcta = CTA.objects.all()
    allcta = allcta.filter(Shift_timing__exact='Morning')
    allcta7 = 50
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    # start = '06:30:00'
    # end = '15:30:00'
    print('Current Time:',current_time)
    try:
        if current_time > '06:30:00' and current_time < '23:59:59':
            if len(count) <= allcta7:
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    movie_resource = CTaResource()
                    print('movie_resource', movie_resource)
                    ##we will get data in movie_resources####
                    dataset = Dataset()
                    print('Dataset ka Type', dataset)
                    new_movie = request.FILES['file']
                    if not new_movie.name.endswith('xls'):
                        messages.info(request, 'Sorry Wrong File Format.Please Upload valid format')
                        return render(request, 'app/uploadcta.html')
                    messages.info(request, 'Starting...')
                    imported_data = dataset.load(new_movie.read(), format='xls')
                    print('abcdefghijk:', type(imported_data))
                    messages.info(request, 'Checking File content)')
                    for data in imported_data:
                        print('data2',data[1])
                        datax=data[1]
                        if data[1] != '' :
                            value = CTA(
                                data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], data[8],
                            )
                            if len(count) <= allcta7:
                                value.save()
                                i = i + 1
                                count.append(i)
                                print('Count After Saving Value:', count)
                                ldap.insert(1, datax)
                                print('Ldap ID is:', ldap)
                                print('Testing')
                        else:
                            if data[1] == '':
                                messages.info(request,
                                              'Please Make Sure AppConnect field value should not be blank. OR')
                            break
                    else:
                        messages.info(request, 'File Processing')
                        messages.success(request, ". . . . .")
                        logger.info('Data present in CTA upload file:  %s !', imported_data)

                        messages.info(request, 'File is Uploded successfully')

            
                    return render(request, 'app/uploadcta.html', {'lap': imported_data})

                        # return render(request, 'apple/wrongtime.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Sorry,File Upload is not allowed')
        
            # return render(request, 'app/wrongtime.html')
    except:
        messages.info(request,'Please Make sure Email field should be unique.')
        

    return render(request,'app/uploadcta.html')
```

Que: how I can print the content by using message.info for example if I will use
messages.info(request, 'File is Uploded successfully')

I will get output :File is Uploded successfully

same way is there any way I can pass content also like how we are passing in render

example : return render(request, 'app/uploadcta.html', {'lap': imported_data})

Answer (score 0):

@Shailesh - How about this approach
how to differentiate which are updated records and which are newly added records?
How about you add these two fields to your model?

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When a record is created then both created_at and modified_at will have the same value
and when a record is updated then modified_at should change but created_at will be the date when the record was inserted.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) but for this I am not able to upload data from .xls file.(It is working fine when I'm uploading it from admin).
If I will use modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) then It is working fine from .xls and admin.(auto_now here I will get only last time when it was updated).